# Nhibernate join queries using futures

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I am trying to pull out a complete object graph using 3 queries and futures to batch the 3 calls.

Here is a cut down version of my object graph.

```
public class Talent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Slug { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Credit> Credits { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Show> Creations { get; set; }
}
```

The Talent query is able to work out how to get the Creators

However the credits don't, I can see another SQL query being generated to fetch this data again.
Here are the queries.

```
//Selectes the root node
var talentQuery = session.QueryOver<Filmslave.Domain.Models.Talent>()
                    .Where(t => t.Slug == slug)
                    .Take(1)
                    .Future();

//Fills Talent.Creations
var creationsQuery = session.QueryOver<Filmslave.Domain.Models.Creator>()
                    .Fetch(c => c.Shows).Eager
                    .JoinQueryOver(c => c.Talent).Where(t => t.Slug == slug)
                    .Future();

//Fills Talent.Credits
var creditsQuery = session.QueryOver<Filmslave.Domain.Models.Credit>()
                    .Fetch(c => c.Role).Eager
                    .Fetch(c => c.Episode).Eager
                    .JoinQueryOver(c => c.Talent).Where(t => t.Slug == slug)
                    .Future();

talent = talentQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I get the talent to pick up it's credits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work like that, but I've also found eager loading relationships using the inverse to be problematic.  If you invert the query it should work:

```
var creditsQuery = session.QueryOver<Filmslave.Domain.Models.Talent>()
                .Where(t => t.Slug == slug)
                .Fetch(t => t.Credits).Eager
                .Fetch(t => t.Credits[0].Role).Eager
                .Fetch(t => t.Credits[0].Episode).Eager                    
                .Future();
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. Can you explain how this t.Credits[0].Role works?

Comment: It's syntax that allows you to tell NHibernate to do a fetch on a child of a child that's a collection (eg. where t.Credits is a collection, t.Credits[0].Role is a way to tell NHibernate to fetch all the Role elements of all the Credit elements belonging to t)